# What is wrong with my argument? (copy of $\beta\omega$ in $\mathbb R$)

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $(a_n)$ be a strictly increasing sequence in $[0,1]$.  Then {$a_n:n\in\omega$} is relatively discrete in $[0,1]$.  So $cl_{[0,1]}${$a_n:n\in\omega$}$\simeq cl_{\beta[0,1]}${$a_n:n\in\omega$}$\simeq\beta\omega$.

I know that you usually need the set to be closed to get that last homeomorphism, and certainly {$a_n:n\in\omega$} is not closed in $[0,1]$.  But I read something which only made reference to the "relatively discrete" part.  And the set in that example was not closed either. What am I missing?

Comment: I am confused: $\beta[0,1] = [0,1]$ as $[0,1]$ is compact already. What theorem exactly are you referring to  for the last supposed homeomorphism?

Comment: If $X$ is normal and $A$ is closed in $X$ then $\beta A\simeq cl_{\beta X} A$

Comment: Is it possible that my question has something to do with F-spaces?

Comment: An $F$-space is such that every co-zero set is $C^{\ast}$ embedded. But $[0,1]$ is not such a space.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Ok, but if it were such a space, would the argument hold?

Comment: If $X$ is an $F$-space and $A$ is a co-zeroset, so when there exists a continuous function $f:X \mapsto [0,1]$ with $f^{-1}[\{0\}] = X \setminus A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the connection with the closure of $A = \{ a_n : n \in \omega \}$ in $\beta [0,1] = [0,1]$ and $\beta \{ a_n : n \in \omega \}$.

What is true is the following:

> If $A \subseteq X$ is a subspace such that every continuous $f : A \to [0,1]$ is continuously extendible over $X$, then $\beta A \cong \mathrm{cl}_{\beta X} ( A )$.  (Actually, you get something stronger.)

As $A$ is a discrete subspace, then every function $A \to [0,1]$ is continuous.  However not all of these functions are continuously extendible to $[0,1]$: take a limit point of $A$ in $[0,1]$, and define a function $f : A \to [0,1]$ so that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there are $u,v \in A \cap ( x - \epsilon , x + \epsilon )$ such that $f(u) = 0$ and $f(v) = 1$.

Comment: So By Tietze's Extension Theorem the conclusion of your highlighted statement holds when $X$ is normal and $A$ is closed in $X$.  Does it also hold if $X$ is completely regular and $A$ is closed?

Comment: @Lusinghiero not necessarily. You need a so-called $C^{\ast}$-embedded subset, as Arthur states.

Comment: And if every closed set is $C^{\ast}$-embedded in it, the space is normal. So every Tychonoff non-normal space has at least one counterexample to your question (in the first comment).